# How to scope to a class instead of a style

Tags: css, less

Is there a way to shorten the following code?

```
.outer-a {
    .inner {
        background-color: white;
    }
}

.outer-b {
    .inner {
        background-color: white;
    }
}
```

My expected output:

```
.outer-a .inner {
    background-color: white;
}

.outer-b .inner {
    background-color: white;
}
```

I can't find any functionality in Less documentation that provides this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can club the parents like

```
.outer-a,
.outer-b {
    .inner {
        background-color: white;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't @extend result in: '.outer-a, .outer-b, .inner {}'?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could try with commas. Something like this:

```
.outer-a, .outer-b {
    .inner {
        background-color: white;
    }
}
```

This then compiles into this

```
.outer-a .inner,
.outer-b .inner {
  background-color: white;
}
```